# print a dictionary except one key:value pair

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to print a dictionary, but avoid one of the key:value pair, the code is,

```
[(key,value) for key, value in row.items() if key is not 'key1']
```

but 'key1' still got printed, how to fix it?

Comment: You want `!=`, not `is`. You are testing for value equality, not if the key is the exact same object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if I tried `[key for key, value in row.items() if key is not 'key1']`, it can actually print all other keys without 'key1'

Comment: Only if you added that key *in the same function or both lines of code are at module scope*. You are getting confused by an implementation detail, where some string literals result in reuse of the same object. Use `!=` **always** when comparing values, unless you know absolutely certain that you want to test the same object.